# Sourcing a .sh file under zsh : addvar:1: bad substitution error message

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, substitution

I have the following `.sh` file that I would like to be able to source under zsh, which is my default shell. The beginning of the file is (after there are only `export variable = path`) :

```
function addvar () {
local tmp="${!1}" ;
tmp="${tmp//:${2}:/:}" ; tmp="${tmp/#${2}:/}" ; tmp="${tmp/%:${2}/}" ;
export $1="${2}:${tmp}" ;
}
```

At the execution : `$ source file.sh`

I get the following error message :

```
addvar:1: bad substitution
```

Could anyone see what's wrong ?

ps : I tried to put directly at the top : `#!/bin/bash` and execute directly by `$ ./file.sh`

but it doesn't do anything (none variables exported).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the following `.sh` file that I would like to be able to source under zsh, which is my default shell.

That filename extension suggests that the file is intended for a Bourne-family shell, but it says nothing about which one, and various members of the family have various incompatibilities with each other.  If there is a shebang line (a line beginning  with `#!` and appearing as the first line of the file) then it *may* give a more specific indication of the shell for which the file is intended, but that has functional relevance only when the file is executed directly, not when it is sourced.

> I get the following error message :
>
> ```
> addvar:1: bad substitution
> ```
>
> Could anyone see what's wrong ?

The problem is with

> ```
> local tmp="${!1}" ;
> ```

, and specifically with `${!1}`.  In Bash, this is an indirect variable reference, which expands to the value of the variable named by the expansion of `${1}`.  In Zsh, however, it is simply invalid, so you cannot use that code as-is in that shell.

It looks like the function is supposed to add the value specified as its second argument to the path-like value of the environment variable named by its first argument, removing any previous appearances of that value.  Since you cannot use it as-is in Zsh, I would suggest just not.  You might instead use a function that computes the appropriate updated value, and leaves the reassignment to the caller. Example:

```sh
add_path_element() {
    local tmp="${1//:${2}:/:}"
    tmp="${tmp/#${2}:/}"
    tmp="${tmp/%:${2}/}"
    echo -n "${tmp}:${2}"
}

# Instead of "addvar PATH /dir/to/add":
export PATH=$(add_path_element "$PATH" /dir/to/add)
```

It should also be possible to implement a version of the original `addvar` function that works in Zsh (and Bash) by use of the `eval` built-in, but I cannot recommend that approach to you because `eval` is very dangerous. I mention it here just in case someone else suggests it.  As a basic rule, do not use `eval` until you are sufficiently expert at shell programming to thoroughly understand why you should not use `eval`.

Comment: `zsh` syntax for indirect parameter expansion would be `local tmp=${(P)1}`.

Comment: You can also simply write `path+=( /dir/to/add )`, which takes care of building the value of `PATH` appriopriately. (`path` is "tied" to the value of `PATH`.)